# Is there a way to control opacity of scene.background in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js, background, opacity

In this [example](https://kubamatuszczak.com/example_gltf) I'd like to have a video background that only becomes visible when the camera is in a certain position (for this purpose right now it's indicated by the background color turning black) Is it possible to make it work instead from *white to black* in terms of fixed HEX opaque colors to *white to transparent* so that it can reveal for example an background image sequence/video set using CSS?? I'm confident it's a pretty weird and flawed way to tackle this problem but i'm trying different approaches. Here's another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639391/controlling-background-video-visibility-using-three-vector3-and-orbitcontrols-js) Any suggestions/explantions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, `scene.background` can only be set [to a color, texture, or cubeMap](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/scenes/Scene.background), which means it cannot have an opacity by default.

However, the *renderer* does have the `alpha` attribute, which lets you render with transparency when there is no `scene.background` to cover the transparent parts. With that in mind, you could do something like this:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true
});

function cameraInPosition() {
    // Removes the colored background
    // allowing you to see video behind the canvas
    scene.background = null;

    // Play whatever video you've placed behind canvas
    playVideoOrSomething();
}
```

It'll jump from opaque background to transparent, but you'll be able to see the video behind the canvas.

Comment: To make things easier for me for now I added a simple background image in body  using CSS (i don't know how to add a full screen video) and I understand Your idea but i don't really  know where to put the code.. btw in the first line shouldn't it be *new THREE.WebGLRenderer* instead of *new WebGLRenderer* or is it a different thing altogehter?

Comment: If you're writing in modern style JavaScript you'll often import just just the bits of three.js that you need, in which case you won't use the THREE namespace. But `THREE.WebGLRenderer` and `WebGLRenderer` are the same.

Comment: Yes, the two are the same. Just make sure you add the `alpha: true` option to your existing renderer initiation. And you already have a variable that knows when the camera is in position, so you can use that to trigger the function above: `if(distance < 0.1) { cameraInPosition();}`

Comment: Ok! Thank you so so much once again! So I put  *if(distance < 0.1) { cameraInPosition();}* inside of *function animate()* and it works. However I wanted it to reset back to opaque background when the user is further away again so that the background doesn't remain visible forever after the user reaches the position just once. Simple *else { scene.background = startColor; }* did the trick :))